# Copy content from one folder to another

Tags: ios, swift, save, nsfilemanager, nsdocument

I'm trying to copy or move a JPG from one folder to another using the code below.

```
func moveItems(originPath: String, destinationPath: String, successBlock:@escaping () -> Void, errorBlock:@escaping (_ error: Error) -> Void) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: originPath, toPath: destinationPath)
        successBlock()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        errorBlock(NSError())
    }
}
```

But i always get the following error:

> open on
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E138FDE0-A036-48D9-8E7C-518B6A5E452C/Documents/tailsImages/:
>   File exists “3A75A51A-0946-45AF-BF1D-F4EB4D71ED68.png” couldn’t be
>   copied to “Documents” because an item with the same name already
>   exists.

There are two problems that I don't understand. One is that the destination folder isn't the "Documents" that the error refers and the other is that the JPG only exists in the destinationPath folder.

> (lldb) po originPath
>   "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E138FDE0-A036-48D9-8E7C-518B6A5E452C/Documents/tailsImagesSync/3A75A51A-0946-45AF-BF1D-F4EB4D71ED68.png"
>
> (lldb) po destinationPath
>   "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E138FDE0-A036-48D9-8E7C-518B6A5E452C/Documents/tailsImages/"

Comment: you should add fileName in destinationPath.

Comment: Check that you are adding your file name to destinationPath, and make sure that  destinationPath is deferent that the originPath, for double  check you can use fileManager.fileExists to check there is no doubleaction.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Post The answer @ivarun

Comment: @bruno Great :) Adding as answer please accept and upvote it will help other to find answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append filename in destinationPath. This will work for you.